# how to read output and provide input to subprocess in java

Tags: java

I want to make a Java program to run another Java program. I wrote some code to run another Java program. `Jhon.java` is a Java file from which I execute the `Add`.class file. But there is problem while reading output and provide input to subprocess. I have this code.

```
import java.io.*;

class Jhon
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            String command="java Add";
            Process proc=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            Thread t1=new A(proc);
            t1.start();
            Thread t2=new B(proc);
            t2.start();
            proc.waitFor();
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {}
    }
}
class A extends Thread
{
    Process proc;
    A(Process proc)
    {
        this.proc=proc;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new       InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try
        {
            while(true)
            {   
                String s = br.readLine();
                OutputStream out = proc.getOutputStream();
                out.write(s.getBytes());
                out.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    } 
}
class B extends Thread
{
    Process proc;
    B(Process proc)
    {
        this.proc=proc;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        try
       {
            String line="";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }
}
```

This is the `Add.java` file which is executed by `Jhon.java` file

```
import java.io.*;

class Add
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a,b,c;
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter first number");
            a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("Enter second number");
            b=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            c=a+b;
            System.out.println("Addition is "+c);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the `Add.java` file from `Jhon.java` file it asks to enter the first number. After providing the first number, it asks to enter the second number. After providing the second number, it does not print addition. The terminal hangs . So what am I doing wrong? Please give me a solution.

Comment: Do your read/write operations within a single thread, so you know at what point your up to

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `class A` reads the first line of input, calls `getOutputStream()` and `os.write()` to (begin to) send that line to the subprocess and then calls `os.close()`. After flushing the data, that closes the pipe that communicates to the standard input of the subprocess. It then loops around to read the next line and tries to `getOutputStream` and `write` and `close` again, but the write does nothing because it is buffered and the close actually fails because the pipe is closed but it suppresses the internal exception, I believe so autoclose is safe. It then waits for further input.
2. Your `class Add` in the subprocess successfully reads the first line; when it tries to read the second line its standard input (the pipe from the master) has been closed normally, which is considered "EOF" (End Of File). `br.readLine()` returns `null` to indicate EOF, but you pass it to `Integer.parseInt` which causes a `NullPointerException`, which isn't caught (it's not a subtype of `IOException`) so the Java default is to display a stacktrace on standard error and exit. Standard error for a subprocess is piped to the master as a separate stream (not "Input" stream) and your master isn't looking at it, so that information is lost.
3. Meanwhile (the thread for) your `class A` is still waiting for input. If you enter whatever the end-of-input signal is on your platform (usually control-D on Unix but can be configured to something else, control-Z on Windows) it will treat that as EOF, `readLine` will return `null` and so `s.getBytes()` will throw a `NullPointerException` which your `catch(IOException){}` will silently discard, and it will exit with no indication of the numerous problems that actually occurred.

Moral: in addition to trying to write correct code in the first place, realize that humans don't get everything perfect every time, so don't throw away exceptions unless you know for *certain* what caused them -- and at your stage of learning you don't know. And try not to throw away other error information either (in this case the error stream from the subprocess).

Fixes:

- call `getOutputStream` only once, and for each input line (in the loop if you keep the loop but see next) do `os.write(line)` and `os.flush()` but NOT `os.close()`.
- either rearrange this to be synchronous as @MadProgrammer commented, or else arrange so that your input-and-send thread `t1` terminates when the subprocess exits, or equivalently when the receive-and-display thread `t2` terminates -- which it does when `br.readLine()==null` indicating EOF because the subprocess exited, which `class B` does test correctly unlike `class A`. This is hard to do automatically because `A` is already sitting in `readLine` which cannot be interrupted, at least not reliably. One simple possibility is to output a message telling the user to now enter the end-of-input signal, and code `A` to handle EOF correctly.
- or, a real kludge but for completeness, make `t1` a daemon thread and *don't* `join` it. Then `main` will return which terminates the main thread once the subprocess has exited and `t2` has terminated, and the JVM will exit without waiting for `t1`. Because this is usually a Bad Idea I won't give you 'teh codez' but a little googling will find how to do this.